# IF function containing AND

Tags: excel-formula

```
If Cell A and B are Null then C will = 0
AND/OR
If Cell A and B are Not Null C will = A - B
```

Can anyone help I need the formula for Cell C?

Answer (score 0):

Excel's documentation about IF function:

> IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])

In our case:

```
logical_test = AND(A1="",B1="")

[value_if_true] = 0

[value_if_false] = A1-B1
```

Therefore:

```
C1 = IF(AND(A1="",B1="")=0, 0, A1-B1)
```

If you are using Google Sheets, you may have to replace the `,` with `;`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in c2 (assuming you have header in row 1):

=IF(A2=0,IF(B2=0,0,A2-B2))

Answer (score 0):

This will give the answer you're after:

```
=IF(AND(A1="",B1=""),0,A1-B1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the *and* in *If Cell A and B are Not Null* is significant and suggest:

```
=(A1<>"")*(B1<>"")*(A1-B1)
```

though this does not apply IF or AND functions. With IF at least the very slightly longer:

```
=IF(OR(A1="",B1=""),0,A1-B1)
```

Others have a different interpretation so I have tried to compare the five answers you have now been offered:

[image: SO33962117 example]

These are so very similar I may have muddled them up but it seems there are two interpretations at least, with a choice for both.